# PHP - Log exec() calls

Tags: php

is there a way to log all calls that to exec() PHP makes? Recording PHP file and line number, and target executable with arguments, for example.

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few options, none of them are great:

- If you have PECL APD installed, you can use [override_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php).
- If you have PECL runkit installed, you can use [runkit_function_redefine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php).
- If you have the ability to wrap all the code in question with a namespace (possibly via the auto_prepend_file setting), you can just define a new exec() function.
- Enable safe_mode and put nothing but a wrapper script in safe_mode_exec_dir. The only thing people will be able to exec is that wrapper, which can log hits and then spawn the requested command.

If you're concerned about what is getting exec()'ed, your best bet is probably just to turn it off by adding it (and its brethren) to the disabled_functions list.